# ggplot2 legend, geom_abline and stat_gg

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have been trying to plot a Normal Q-Q plot  with a red line across, in R with ggplot2. I have been unable to add a legend (with LaTeX math) to explain the red line

Here is the code for the basic figure:

```
ggplot(stdres_df, aes(sample=stdres)) + 
  stat_qq(color="black") +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, 
              intercept = 0, color ="red")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: This is my last unsuccessful attempt:

`code`
ggplot(stdres_df, aes(sample=stdres)) + 
  stat_qq(color="black") +
  geom_abline(aes(linetype = "line"), slope = 1, 
              intercept = 0, color ="red")
  scale_color_manual("",
                     labels = c("line"="Test"))

Comment: It would help if you provide a minimal dataset. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a legend, you need to map something to a color aesthetic inside a call to `aes()`. In this case, there's no grouping variable to map to colour, but you can just map colour to the name you want to use for the red line.

The line will be red by default, because ggplot uses `hcl(15, 100, 65)` (a light red) as the first color in its default color palette. However, you can set the color to whatever you want using `scale_colour_manual`, as shown in the example below. For example:

```
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(200))

ggplot(df, aes(sample = y)) + 
  stat_qq() +
  geom_abline(aes(slope=1, intercept=0, colour="Test"), size=1) +
  coord_equal(xlim=range(df$y)) +
  labs(colour="") +
  scale_colour_manual(values="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
ggplot() + 
stat_qq(aes(sample=1:100), distribution = qt,dparams = list(df=5)) +
geom_abline(aes(linetype = "line"), slope = 1, intercept = 0, color ="red") +
geom_text(aes(3, 0, label = "TEXT HERE"))
```

Comment: This does not work, "geom_abline(): Ignoring `mapping` because `slope` and/or `intercept` were provided." This is despite it being consistent with how legends can be done for geom_smooth.